# About the Wrong position of coordinate magnitude in 3D figure using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.10, matplotlib-3d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K4UM.png)

Wrong position of coordinate magnitude in 3D figure，How to correct this bug ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YcDH.png)
I tried to use Scientific notation for every number on its coordinate axis, but the number display is too dense and the effect is not good.
I want it to display the correct position like a 2D image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.